# Tangential acceleration.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I know that the tangential component of acceleration is:

$$\frac{d^2}{dt^2}s$$

Where is $s$ is the distance traveled in $t$ units of time:

$$s(t)=\int_{0}^{t} ||\vec r'(u)|| du$$

Im directly computing the component of $a=\vec r''(t)$ in the direction of $ \vec r'(t)$ using the dot product.

To get:

$$a_{||}=\text{comp}_{\vec r'(t)}\vec r''(t)=\frac{\vec r'(t)• \vec r''(t)}{||\vec r'(t)||}$$

Where • denotes the dot product. How can I go from here to show they are the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $s(t)$ be given by the integral

$$s(t)=\int_0^t |\vec r'(u)|\,du \tag 1$$

Assuming that $|\vec r'(u)|$ is sufficiently smooth (e.g., continuous), then the fundamental theorem of calculus guarantees that

$$\begin{align}
\frac{ds(t)}{dt}&=|\vec r'(t)|\\\\
&=\sqrt{\vec r'(t)\cdot \vec r'(t)} \tag 2
\end{align}$$

In arriving at $(2)$, we simply wrote the magnitude of $\vec r'(u)$ as the square root of the inner product of $\vec r'(u)$ with itself.

Taking the second derivative of $s(t)$ as given by $(2)$ reveals

$$\begin{align}
\frac{d^2s(t)}{dt^2}&=\frac12\frac{1}{\sqrt{\vec r'(t)\cdot \vec r'(t)}}\frac{d}{dt}(\vec r'(t)\cdot \vec r'(t))\\\\
&=\frac{\vec r'(t)\cdot \vec r''(t)}{\sqrt{\vec r'(t)\cdot \vec r'(t)}}\\\\
&=\frac{\vec r'(t)\cdot \vec r''(t)}{|\vec r'(t)|}
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: You are quite welcome.  My pleasure.   -Mark